# Закладки и новые окна в Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

Есть такая часть кода:

```
$("#btnPublishAll").click(function (evt) {
    $("input:checkbox[name='visitselect']:checked").each(function (i, obj) {
        var url = "[@spring.url " / visit / publicate "/]?id=" + $(obj).attr("data-visit");
        window.open(url);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Я хочу чтобы каждое последующее окно открывалось как новая вкладка, а не новое окно. Что я имею: первая ссылка открывается как вкладка, а все последующие - как новые окна :/ 
Что делать?

Comment: `window.open(url, '_blank');` пробовали? Вообще Вы не можете контролировать как будут открываться новые ссылки, в табе или в окне, так как это настройки браузера, которые недоступны для изменения через javascript

Comment: Пробовал, не работает. Забавно что эта проблема встречается только в хроме

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ссылка открывалась в новой табе

```
<a href="/bla-bla" target="_blank">bla-bla</a>
```

Чтоб ссылка открывала новое окно

```
<a href="/bla-bla" onClick="window.open(this.href, 'newWin');return false">bla-bla</a>
```

При дефолтных настройках браузера это должно работать верно.
А теперь касательно Вашего кода:

```
$("#btnPublishAll").click(function (evt) {
    $("input:checkbox[name='visitselect']:checked").each(function (i, obj) {
        var url = "[@spring.url " / visit / publicate "/]?id=" + 
                  $(obj).attr("data-visit");
        $('<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">link</a>').appendTo("body").click().remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Благодарю!